# Displaying Multiple Images in java

Tags: java, swing, uiimageview

I've developed an Image search engine which works on object.

The only problem is with displaying search results. Since, we are using java, so the UI is not very good for now.. can any one suggest how to display many images (search results) (number of images per page based on users preference) in a JFrame.

Also how to create a good GUI for displaying search results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I advise you to use a [JList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html), which allows you to display a list of items. By default, the items are displayed as strings, but you can easily customize the way an item is renderered: you just create a custom [ListCellRenderer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ListCellRenderer.html). A ListCellRenderer may well display an image within the list cell.

You may read the [chapter about lists on the Java tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html), and in particular [the section about ListCellRenderer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer).

Comment: +1, for the general suggestion to use a JList and for the link to the tutorial. However, then is no need to create a custom renderer. You just add an ImageIcon to the ListModel and it will render properly.

Comment: @camickr: ListModel does not allow you to return an icon for a given index... ListModel returns an Object for a given index, and the Object is rendered by the ListCellRenderer. What were you suggesting?

Comment: @camickr: oh ok I see. The default ListCellRenderer knows how to render icon objects properly. That's it.